# How to get list of all routes I am using in restify server

Tags: node.js, restify

I have a app designed as follows;

```
//server.js =====================================================
var restify = require('restify'),
    route1 = require('./routes/route1),
    route2 = require('./routes/route2),
    ....
    ....
    ....

var server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'xyz_server'
  });

route1(server);
route2(server);
```

Now each route file looks like belwo

```
   //route1.js =====================================================

   module.exports = function(server) {
      server.get('/someRoute',function(req,res,next){
                //.. do something
        });
      server.get('/anotherRoute',function(req,res,next){
                 //..something else
       });

   };
```

Now the issue is tht we have dozen's of route files and hundreds of routes in total.
There are multiple developers working on this project and several routes are being added daily.

Is there a function in restify gives me a list of all routes in the system ?

What i am looking for is something like:

```
server.listAllRoutes();
```

Is anyone aware of this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this

```
function listAllRoutes(server){
  console.log('GET paths:');
  server.router.routes.GET.forEach(
    function(value){console.log(value.spec.path);}
    );
  console.log('PUT paths:');
  server.router.routes.PUT.forEach(
    function(value){console.log(value.spec.path);}
    );
}

listAllRoutes(server);
```

This should list all GET and PUT paths, adding POST and DELETE should be easy :)

Answer (score 2):

2019 update: `server.router.routes` is no longer available instead we have `server.router.getRoutes()` which returns a Map. So we can log all the routes using:

```
function listAllRoutes(server) {
  Object.values(server.router.getRoutes()).forEach(value =>
    console.log(
      `ENDPOINT REGISTERED :: ${value.method} :: ${server.url}${value.path}`
    )
  );
}
```

http://restify.com/docs/server-api/#server

Answer (score 1):

There is a `router.getRoutes()` method, but it returns an object which is not the best to work with for listing things. You could fiddle around with that to turn it into an array with the shape that you like.

Alternatively, you can access all the routes as an array and then map them, even better if you use a lib like `better-console` to give you `console.table` in node. The following is working nicely for me in `restify@8.3.0`:

```
import console from 'better-console';

function listRoutes(server) {
  const { routes } = server.router._registry._findMyWay; // beware these are probably meant to be private APIs, they could be subject to change
  const mapped = routes.map(({ method, path }) => ({ method, path }));

  console.table(mapped.sort((a, b) => a.method > b.method));
}
```